# RAID1 disks on new windows 7 installation

Tags: windows, raid1

I have a PC with Windows 7 on one disk A. Two other disks B and C are software (Windows 7 disk management) RAID1 mirrored. I want to reinstall Windows 7 on the first disk A. Will the new Windows 7 installation recognize the RAID1 set?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The Windows fault-tolerant disk driver marks RAID volumes such that they will be automatically detected.

If you want to see it for yourself non-destructively just boot the Windows 7 setup DVD, open a command-prompt (Shift-F10), run `DISKPART`, and execute a `LIST VOLUME`. You'll see the volumes w/ software RAID identified under the "Type" column.

```
...
DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C                NTFS   Mirror        60 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 1     D                NTFS   Mirror      1802 GB  Healthy
  Volume 2                      NTFS   Mirror       100 MB  Healthy    System
```

Comment: Great! I will try that with the boot dvd. Thanks Evan.